# How can I pass a map operation to a component (react datepicker) as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

```
          <DatePicker
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={handleStartDate}
            locale="uk"
            dateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy"
            placeholderText="Дата початку"
            filterDate={isWeekday}
            minDate={moment().toDate()}
            showMonthPicker
          {Object.keys(dateErr).map((key) => {
            return <div className={css.error}>{dateErr[key]}</div>;
          })}
          />
```

I need to pass a map operation to a library called "react-datepicker" as a prop, right now the implementation isn't right, need to know how can I pass it

Comment: The map function returns an array, which you need to pass to the DatePicker component. If that's the case, you have to specify a property name, so the component can access it with that name. If you want to pass the array as children, you can write it between the opening and closing tags of the DatePicker like so:
<DatePicker ...props >{array}</DatePicker>

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you want to do, what props do you want to pass the map function to?

Answer (score 1):

As [@Muhammad B. Aydemir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8375744/muhammed-b-aydemir) already pointed out and as it is stated in the [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) documentation on the children example, you can only add DatePicker children in between the opening and closing tag whether it is a single component or an array of components. Do not forget to add the unique key attribute to each of the children in the passed array or you will get errors. In your case it would look something like:

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={handleStartDate}
  locale="uk"
  dateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy"
  placeholderText="Дата початку"
  filterDate={isWeekday}
  minDate={moment().toDate()}
  showMonthPicker
/>
  {Object.keys(dateErr).map((key, index) => {
    return <div key={index} className={css.error}>{dateErr[key]}</div>;
  })}
</DatePicker>
```